# why does twenty eleven theme mix up the css measurement units?

Tags: theme-development, css, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm wondering why does WordPress's default theme mix up the css measurement units?

For example:

```
.one-column.singular #author-info {
margin: 2.2em -8.8% 0;
padding: 20px 8.8%;}
```

Wouldn't be easier to understand and to work if all them were pixel based?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having CSS use relative (%) and fixed(px) attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its just a css thing... while the distance from the top object is

to remain permenant the distance from a side object is relative and

those changes (sometimes) as the screen resulotion changes..**

That prevents smaller screens from having a broken site. Anyhow thats
the old way to go about it (in a matter of speaking) since "Responsive website design"
is the modern way to control website fluidity...